# Only one active div allowed using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have 3 divs each with class `item` and only one can have class `active` at a time.  For example:

```
<div class="item active">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
```

I have a jQuery binding code that activates a div on the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item').bind('click', function() {
        addClass('active');        
        // now I need to remove active class from the previous selected item
    });
});
```

What is the best way of doing the housekeeping where I would remove the active class from any other div that may be active?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to use `$(this).addClass`, not just on it's own, also, you can remove `active` class from all elements with `active` class before hand - like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item').bind('click', function() {
        // remove the active class from all elements with active class
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
        // add active class to clicked element
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, I like this one because it does not need to look at any of the other .item divs.  Should be fast if there are many divs.

Answer (score 5):

As a one liner, you can add the active class, then remove it from all the siblings

```
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/nAnpn/1/

Comment: Man be happy! You save my life now :D

Answer (score 2):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nAnpn/)**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.item').bind('click', function() {
            $('.item').removeClass('active').filter($(this)).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This could do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $items = $('.item');
    $items.bind('click', function() {
        $items.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

With this solution you'll lookup for the items only once. So keep in mind that future `.item` elements won't work as you expected, but it'll be faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove it from all divs of class item before you add it to the new one:

```
$('.item').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

That way you don't have to worry about keeping track of the previous active element, just remove from all and add to the selected one.

Answer (score 1):

Before adding "active" class, you should remove the current "active" class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item').bind('click', function() {
        addClass('active');        
        $('.item').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and wanted to leave this method. This retains the ability to remove the active class from other elements and still allows the clicked element to toggle, need be.

```
$(".item").click(function(){
    $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');      
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, I'm not very good in this but what about removing the class and only adding item back in again like:

```
$('div').removeClass('item active').addClass('item');
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd recommend putting them all in one container. Then you can remove the `active` class from all of the siblings (in case you want more than one group of items throughout the page).

```
$(function() {
  $(".item").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);                           // store jQuery object
    $this.siblings(".item").removeClass("active"); // remove from all .items
    $this.addClass("active");                      // add to clicked item
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/brymck/kT7vP/2/)

Note also that if you're designing something best represented with radio buttons, you can do basic styling of the checked element with just HTML and CSS:

[HTML+CSS example for forms](http://jsfiddle.net/brymck/yxnke/1/)